# App file in React does'nt recognize jsx syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is really quite weird. My (App.js) file recognizes jsx syntax fine when App is a function,
however when I convert it into a class it doesn't recognize jsx at all.

Here's the code:

*recognizes jsx when App is a function*

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Counters from './components/counters';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

function App() {
  return ( <h1></h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

*but when I convert it to a class it doesn't recognize jsx*:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Counters from './components/counters';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  return ( <h1></h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was following a tutorial, and in the tutorial (App) was a class and it worked just fine.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to write your template in render method when using class components.

Comment: You nedd to have `render` method  in your class [Read more](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a class component, the return statement needs to be inside a render method, like this:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Counters from './components/counters';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (<h1></h1>);
  }
}

export default App;
```